# Improve performance of string builder

Tags: c#, .net

Can extensive `StringBuilder.Append()` operations be optimized by using `char[]` allocated on thread's stack to build the string by character using pointers?

```
        unsafe
        {
            const Int32 width = 1024;

            Char* msg = stackalloc Char[width];

            Int32 index = 0;

            property = Environment.MachineName;

            for (Int32 i = 0; i < property.Length; i++)
                    msg[index++] = property[i];             

            return new String(msg, 0, width);
        }
```

This gives about 25% improvement compared to using `StringBuilder` and not quite satisfying as a result.

Comment: @Nuffin Umm, perhaps the very first line? Just needs a question mark. However, the question seems at odds with the second line, perhaps the OP wants a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Have you experimentally measured that using StringBuilder.Append is a bottleneck for your application and you really need to descend to the pointer and unsafe code level? Or are you just prematurely attempting to save a couple of CPU cycles without a solid reason?

Comment: A StringBuilder can have an initial capacity which probably would give you the same benefits as a char array, have you tried it with different initial capacities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an idea up front about how big your final string is going to be (as it seems you do), you can construct the `StringBuilder` with that capacity to start with, so it spends less time reallocating space:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();   
// capacity 16, will expand as needed

var sb30000 = new StringBuilder(30000);   
// capacity 30000, will not need to expand until that length is passed
```

which might help a bit.

Comment: THat pretty much is it - reallocation DOES cost time. After that I would say you have to have VERY VERY VERY special code for the difference to REALLY make a difference.